# Contact Form 7 - Redirect page to specific URL based on drop-down selection

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, contacts, contact-form-7

I have read several forums on this topic, but have not been able to get any of the fixes to work for me. That is due partially to the fact that I am not familiar with JS and may not be understanding some of the values suggested.

My form needs to open a PDF on submit, but which PDF would be determined by one of the dropdown selections.

The form is here: http://www.hinesbending.com/production/index.php/request-info-form/

The dropdown is Download Document.

Upon clicking Send, I would like the page to open the PDF in a new window if possible, and still show the message under the form that "Your message was sent successfully. Thanks."

If that is not possible, simply redirecting to the appropriate PDF would suffice.

Can anyone tell me how to do this, please?

Answer (score 1):

These worked for me:

```
on_sent_ok: "var Iso = $("select[name=your-selection-name]").val() ; 
if(Iso == 'your-value-1' ){ 
   location = 'your-website1-url'; 
} 
if(Iso == 'your-value-2' ){ 
   location = 'your-website2-url'; 
} 
if(Iso == 'your-value-3' ){ 
   location = 'your-website3-url'; 
}"
```

Just replace `your-selection-name`, `your-values` and `your-websites`

Answer (score 1):

The question is getting old and Contact Form 7 will abolish the on_sent_ok hook:

> Note: The method using on_sent_ok hook is no longer recommended. This function is scheduled to be abolished by the end of 2017. (https://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/)

Thats why we need a different approach with **DOM events** (https://contactform7.com/dom-events/)

Contact Form 7 gives an example for the redirect:

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    location = 'https://www.example.com';
}, false );
```

I would also be interested in how we can combine the dom redirect with a dropdown option